# Is there any way to use the Play DB evolutions in Spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, playframework

We have implemented one of our services using Play framework and another one we are trying to write in Spring-boot. In Play we have used evolutions lib for managing DB evolutions, is there any way to use the Play database evolutions in Spring-boot application.

I couldn't figure out a way to do this, but I can find alternate for Spring-boot DB evolutions using https://flywaydb.org. We have already familiar with Play evolutions, it would be great if there is any workaround to use Play evolutions in Spring-boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot is very opinionated framework and it will be your best fried if you are not trying to resist defaults.

Flyway (or Liquibase which Spring Boot also supports) are very easy to grasp. Anyone skilled with DB migration tool and SQL databases should pick them up nearly instantly. So I would suggest to switch to Flyway or Liquibase.